# Why should I prefer the "explicitly typed initializer" idiom over explicitly giving the type

Tags: c++, c++11, effective-c++

I've recently bought the new Effective modern C++ from Scott Meyers and reading through it now. But I have encountered one thing which totally bugs me.

In item 5, Scott says that using `auto` is a great thing. It saves typing, gives you in most cases the correct type and it might be immune to type mismatches. I totally understand this and think of `auto` as a good thing too.

But then in item 6, Scott says that every coin has two sides. Likewise, there might be cases when `auto` deduces a totally wrong type, e.g. for proxy objects.

You may already know this example:

```
class Widget;
std::vector<bool> features(Widget w);

Widget w;

bool priority = features(w)[5]; // this is fine

auto priority = features(w)[5]; // this result in priority being a proxy
                                // to a temporary object, which will result
                                // in undefined behavior on usage after that
                                // line
```

So far, so good.

But Scott's solution to this, is the so called "explicitly typed initializer idiom". The idea is, to use static_cast on the initializer like this:

```
auto priority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);
```

But this not only leads to more typing, but means you also explicitly state the type, which should be deduced. You basically lose both advantages of `auto` over an explicit given type.

Can anyone tell me, why it is advantageous to use this idiom?

---

First to clear things up, my questions aims to why I should write:

```
auto priority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);
```

instead of:

```
bool priority = features(w)[5];
```

@Sergey brought up a link to a nice article on [GotW](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) about this topic, which partly answers my question.

> Guideline: Consider declaring local variables auto x = type{ expr }; when you do want to explicitly commit to a type. It is self-documenting to show that the code is explicitly requesting a conversion, it guarantees the variable will be initialized, and it won’t allow an accidental implicit narrowing conversion. Only when you do want explicit narrowing, use ( ) instead of { }.

Which basically brings me to a related question. Which of these *four* alternatives should I choose?

```
bool priority = features(w)[5];

auto priority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);

auto priority = bool(features(w)[5]);

auto priority = bool{features(w)[5]};
```

Number one is still my favorite. It's less typing and as explicit as the three other ones.

The point about the guaranteed initialization doesn't really hold, as I'm declaring variables anyways not before I can initialize them somehow. And the other argument about the narrowing didn't work out well in [a quick test](http://ideone.com/GXvIIr).

Comment: I read his books (not this one), and I doubt he didn't explain.

Comment: @Niall: From what I understand the question is not why this is needed, but why put the type in `static_cast` rather than in place of `auto`

Comment: @PiotrS. exactly that's my point.

Comment: @BЈовић unfortunately not. He added a side note for another case, where you intentionally have to cast from double to int.

Comment: @PiotrS. Why put the type in `static_cast` is explained in the comment (i.e., to avoid UB). I think that what the author is trying to say is to use his solution only to specific situations as the illustrated example. There's no need to use it when use of `auto` doesn't cause any implications.

Comment: @40two: nah... the question is why Scott has invented an idiom that looks: `auto x = static_cast<Y>(z);` for what can be expressed as `Y x = z;`

Comment: And, `Y x=e;` is better because `auto x=static_cast<Y>(e);` activates `explicit` conversions, which should be used with caution.  I suspect annotation saying the return value should not be persisted past the invoked line might be in order for C++.

Comment: About your test for narrowing: that code should not compile. The compiler you checked is not correctly implementing brace initialization. Presumably it will get fixed. http://rextester.com/SFTL92198

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Following the C++ Standard:

> #### **§ 8.5 Initializers `[dcl.init]`**
>
> 15. The initialization that occurs in the form
>
>     ```
>     T x = a;
>     ```
>
>     as well as in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) is called *copy-initialization*.

I can think of the example given in the book:

```
auto x = features(w)[5];
```

as the one that represents any form of *copy-initialization* with auto / template type (*deduced type* in general), just like:

```
template <typename A>
void foo(A x) {}

foo(features(w)[5]);
```

as well as:

```
auto bar()
{
    return features(w)[5];
}
```

as well as:

```
auto lambda = [] (auto x) {};
lambda(features(w)[5]);
```

So the point is, we cannot always just *"move type T from `static_cast<T>` to the left-hand side of assignment"*.

Instead, in any of the above examples we need to explicitly specify the desired type rather than allowing compiler deduce one on its own, if the latter can lead to *undefined behavior*:

Respectively to my examples that would be:

```
/*1*/ foo(static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]));

/*2*/ return static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);

/*3*/ lambda(static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]));
```

As such, using `static_cast<T>` is an elegant way of forcing a desired type, which alternatively can be expressed by explicit contructor call:

```
foo(bool{features(w)[5]});
```

---

To summarize, I don't think the book says:

> Whenever you want to force the type of a variable, use `auto x = static_cast<T>(y);` instead of `T x{y};`.

To me it sounds more like a word of warning:

> The type inference with `auto` is cool, but may end up with undefined behavior if used unwisely.

And as a solution for the scenarios *involving type deduction*, the following is proposed:

> If the compiler's regular type-deduction mechanism is not what you want, use `static_cast<T>(y)`.

---

**UPDATE**

And answering your updated question, *which of the below initializations should one prefer*:

```
bool priority = features(w)[5];

auto priority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);

auto priority = bool(features(w)[5]);

auto priority = bool{features(w)[5]};
```

**Scenario 1**

First, imagine the `std::vector<bool>::reference` is **not implicitly** convertible to `bool`:

```
struct BoolReference
{
    explicit operator bool() { /*...*/ }
};
```

Now, the `bool priority = features(w)[5];` will **not compile**, as it is not an explicit boolean context. The others will work fine (as long as the `operator bool()` is accessible).

**Scenario 2**

Secondly, let's assume the `std::vector<bool>::reference` is implemented in an *old fashion*, and although the *conversion operator* is not `explicit`, it returns `int` instead:

```
struct BoolReference
{
    operator int() { /*...*/ }
};
```

The change in signature **turns off** the `auto priority = bool{features(w)[5]};` initialization, as using `{}` prevents the *narrowing* (which converting an `int` to `bool` is).

**Scenario 3**

Thirdly, what if we were talking not about `bool` at all, but about some *user-defined* type, that, to our surprise, declares `explicit` constructor:

```
struct MyBool
{
    explicit MyBool(bool b) {}
};
```

Surprisingly, once again the `MyBool priority = features(w)[5];` initialization will **not compile**, as the copy-initialization syntax requires non-explicit constructor. Others will work though.

**Personal attitude**

If I were to choose one initialization from the listed four candidates, I would go with:

```
auto priority = bool{features(w)[5]};
```

because it introduces an explicit boolean context (which is fine in case we want to assign this value to boolean variable) and prevents narrowing (in case of other types, not-easily-convertible-to-bool), so that when an error/warning is triggered, we can diagnose what `features(w)[5]` **really is**.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have recently watched Herb Sutter's speech from *CppCon 2014* titled [*Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64), where he presents some points on why should one prefer the *explicit type initializer* of `auto x = T{y};` form (though it is not the same as with `auto x = static_cast<T>(y)`, so not all arguments apply) over `T x{y};`, which are:

1. `auto` variables must always be initialized. That is, you can't write `auto a;`, just like you can write error-prone `int a;`
2. The *modern C++* style prefers the type on the right side, just like in:

   a) Literals:

   ```
   auto f = 3.14f;
   //           ^ float
   ```

   b) User-defined literals:

   ```
   auto s = "foo"s;
   //            ^ std::string
   ```

   c) Function declarations:

   ```
   auto func(double) -> int;
   ```

   d) Named lambdas:

   ```
   auto func = [=] (double) {};
   ```

   e) Aliases:

   ```
   using dict = set<string>;
   ```

   f) Template aliases:

   ```
   template <class T>
   using myvec = vector<T, myalloc>;
   ```

   **so as such**, adding one more:

   ```
   auto x = T{y};
   ```

   is consistent with the style where we have name on the left side, and type with initializer on the right side, what can be briefly described as:

   ```
   <category> name = <type> <initializer>;
   ```
3. With copy-elision and non-explicit copy/move constructors it has *zero-cost* compared to `T x{y}` syntax.
4. It is more explicit when there are subtle differences between the types:

   ```
    unique_ptr<Base> p = make_unique<Derived>(); // subtle difference

    auto p = unique_ptr<Base>{make_unique<Derived>()}; // explicit and clear
   ```
5. `{}` guarantees no implicit conversions and no narrowing.

But he also mentions some drawbacks of the `auto x = T{}` form in general, which has already been described in this post:

1. Even though the compiler can elide the right-hand side's temporary, it requires an accessible, non-deleted and non-explicit copy-constructor:

   ```
    auto x = std::atomic<int>{}; // fails to compile, copy constructor deleted
   ```
2. If the elision is not enabled (e.g. `-fno-elide-constructors`), then moving non-movable types results in expensive copy:

   ```
    auto a = std::array<int,50>{};
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your input, in these cases, I see some benefits for using the static_cast, but I don't see, why it is related to my original question? I mean, just because there is also an `auto` somewhere doesn't mean, you have to obey the same rules.

Comment: @Mario: because the same rules of deducing the type are applied.

Comment: @Mario: I don't think the book says: "Whenever you want to force the type of a variable, use `auto x = static_cast<T>(y);` instead of `T x{y};`". To me it looks as just a hint the book gives how to force the desired type, skipping the regular type-deduction mechanism.

Comment: I'm still not convinced, that it's a good idea for the given code, but I see your point for the other cases. This might be the thing, that Scott had in his mind.

Comment: It seems pointless to compare these four `auto x = y as T` cases and avoid `T x{y};`...

Comment: It is not pointless if we talk about copy-initialization syntax in general (see my first paragraphs), not simple assignment like `auto x = z;`, but e.g. template argument deduction that follows the same rules as `auto`.

Comment: I think it would be nice to update your answer to include guaranteed copy elision (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) which is now a part of C++17, enabling the use of auto more frequently.

Answer (score 15):

I don't have the book in front of me, so I can't tell if there's more context.

But to answer your question, no, using `auto`+`static_cast` in this particular example is not a good solution.  It violates another guideline (one for which I've never seen any exceptions justified):

- **Use the weakest cast/conversion possible.**

Unnecessarily strong casts subvert the type system and prevent the compiler from generating diagnostic messages in case a change occurs elsewhere in the program that affects the conversion in an incompatible way.  (action at a distance, the boogey-man of maintenance programming)

Here the `static_cast` is unnecessarily strong.  An implicit conversion will do just fine.  So avoid the cast.

Comment: I really like your answer, but I've got the feeling, that @Piotr S. 's answer is more in the direction, on how it is meant in the book.

Comment: @Mario: The explicit constructor call `T var{expression}` is indeed better, because it doesn't defeat the type system as strongly as `static_cast`.  And, where possible, `T var = expression;` may be preferred because it's even weaker, although unnecessarily permitting explicit constructor invocation is arguably a lot less problematic than the introduction of a cast.

Answer (score 8):

Context from the book:

> Though `std::vector<bool>` conceptually holds `bool`s, `operator[]` for `std::vector<bool>` doesn’t return a reference to an element of the container (which is what `std::vector::operator[]` returns  for every type except `bool`). Instead, it returns an object of type `std::vector<bool>::reference` (a class nested inside `std::vector<bool>`).

There is no advantage, it is more error prevention, when you using auto with external library.

I think, this is the main idea of such idiom. You should be explicit and force auto to behave correctly.

BTW, here the nice article on [GotW](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) about auto.

Comment: Well, `std::vector<T>::operator[]` _always_ returns a `std::vector<T>::reference`; it just so happens that `std::vector<bool>::reference` is not `bool&` :) (replace with `const_reference` and `bool const&` for `std::vector<T>::operator[] const`).

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone tell me, why it is advantageous to use this idiom?

The reason I can think of: because it is explicit. Consider how you would (instinctively) read this code (i.e., whithout knowing what `features` does):

```
bool priority = features(w)[5];
```

"Features returns an indexable sequence of some generic "boolean" values; we read the fifth one into `priority`".

```
auto priority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);
```

"Features returns an indexable sequence of values explicitly convertible to `bool`; we read the fifth one into `priority`".

This code is not written to optimize for shortest flexible code, but for explicitness of the result (and apparently consistency - since I assume it would not be the only variable declared with auto).

The use of auto in the declaration of `priority` is for keeping the code flexible to whatever expression is on the right-hand-side.

That said, I would prefer the version without an explicit cast.

Comment: Except that (for parallelism with the second statement) the first is "values compatible with bool", not necessarily already bool.  Or was that the point you were making using "boolean" vs `bool`?

Comment: "The use of auto in the declaration of priority is for keeping the code flexible to whatever expression is on the right-hand-side" -- but can `auto` produce any type other than `bool` when initialised by an expression `static_cast<bool>(...)`?  I want to say "Of course not", in which case there's no advantage to choosing `auto`, but C++ has some strange corners.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, the truth is, I'm not entirely convinced myself (i.e. I'd probably declare the variable as `bool` and be done with it). One advantage of keeping the `static_cast` (I just thought of this): When refactoring, seeing the explicit cast may be an indication that the call to `features` should be extracted into a function returning `bool` (especially if the construct repeats in client code).

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, this is what I meant (I have edited the response to make it a bit clearer). My interpretations of the client code are pretty subjective though.